# Play Video files in fedora

Tags: fedora, video

I installed a Fedora 18 and added rpm-fusion repositories for fedora18 and also installed all gstreamer codec such as good, ugly, bad, but I can not play videos with `.mkv` , `.mp4`, `.wmv` , extensions yet.

it shows this error when I play a video file:

[image]

of course I should say that `.webm` and `.flv` videos play very well and I don't want to use **VLC**!

Comment: Why don't you want to use VLC? It's a great player. What player are you currently using/would like to use?

Answer (score 2):

What player are you using? Installing (s)mplayer takes care of almost every format.

Comment: I'm using gnome default video player and i want to use codecs, not VLC and others!

Comment: Codecs are just a means to an end. They cannot be used directly to play files.

Comment: The smplayer part is an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
yum install gstreamer-{ffmpeg,plugins-{good,ugly,bad{,-free{,-extras},-nonfree}}}
```

That will get you a few codecs not in your list above. You may also need the `extras` packages. I'm unsure what they are off the top of my head (and don't have access to a Fedora machine at the moment).

Try searching:

```
yum search gstreamer*extra
```

**EDIT:** I think the package I was thinking of is gstreamer-plugins-{good,ugly,bad}-free-extras. I've added it above. If it fails, remove the `{,-extras}`.

Comment: yum says that latest version of these packages are installed.

Comment: My mistake then; I setup a new Fedora 18 install a few days ago and I thought this is all I had to do. You're trying to play an un-encrypted movie right? Or are you trying to watch DVD's (in which case you also want `libdvdread libdvdcss libdvdnav`)?

Comment: You might also try adding `ffmpeg ffmpeg-libs`; I can't remember if I used those or not. As soon as I can get back to my Fedora install I'll let you know exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

This is for those who come here more recently (2016) and don't have a clue what rpm-fusion is (this answer came up in my search for ['fedora play mp4'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fedora+play+mp4))

rpm-fusion has moved to [UnitedRPMs](https://unitedrpms.github.io/). They are a separate repository to the standard Fedora libraries and contain a load of major applications, e.g.:

- Chromium and Opera browsers
- VLC and smplayer (mentioned in the other answers here) media players
- VirtualBox
- Atom and Lighttable IDEs

Their [installation instructions](https://github.com/UnitedRPMs/unitedrpms.github.io/blob/master/README.md) worked perfectly for me (Fedora 24). I installed VLC, rather than smplayer.